# How to convert beforefilter from cakephp to Django?

Tags: django, cakephp, django-rest-framework

I am moving website created in cakephp to Django rest framework.

In cakephp, every controller has parent class as AppController. There is beforefilter in AppController
which is checking authentication/permission and depending on permission other function is being called to set value of public variable present in that class.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
     public temp1 = '';
     public temp2 = array();
     public function beforeFilter(){
         
     }
}
```

I want to create it using Django Rest Framework and send json response to the react app. As far as login authentication is concerned, I used simple-jwt.

```
class index(APIView):
      def get(self,request):
          data = {}
          return JsonResponse(data)
```

Do I need to implement AppController in django separately, create function beforefilter() and call beforefilter() every time I create any api and What about checking whether user is authenticated or not ? Is there any simpler method to apply beforefilter?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the `permission_classes` attribute.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class index(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self,request):
        ...
```

Then the above APIView can only be used by authenticated users.

Comment: after adding permission classes, I am getting `Forbidden: /mypage/`

Comment: Don't you use authentication or something?

Comment: I found the problem in authentication, I forgot to add `REST_FRAMEWORK={'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',)}` Thank you